# ng-controller inside a angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In many tutorials, I've seen controllers being passed into a directive like this:

```
.directive("mainRightPanel", function(){
  return {
        templateUrl: "views/partials/panels/mainRightPanel.html",
        controller: function($http, $filter, $scope) {
            var info = this;
            $scope.authorWorks;
            $http.get('test/book_data.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.authorWorks= data;
            });
          },
}
```

However, I'd like to do it differently. Instead of writing javascript like the above, I'm having problems calling a controller from within the directive, like this

```
<div ng-app="mainLeftPanelModule" ng-controller="leftPanelController" class="list-group ">
```

Is this possible? And if it is, is there anything wrong with attaching a controller this way?

Comment: Controllers in directives are "auto-call" with jus the use of the directive you do not need to use ngController

Comment: @Dalorzo thank you, but I'm trying to see if I can call the controller from within the directive, and NOT have to link the controller from the directive definition!

Comment: you can use ng-controller anywhere. Even inside a directive template. Are you having troubles with that?

Comment: @rob you're right! I think I made a mistake by having ng-app and ng-controller on the same div. If you answer my question, I'll be sure to mark it as the correct one, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put an ng-controller anywhere inside your ng-app including inside a directive template. for example this should work:

```
.directive("mainRightPanel", function(){
    return {
    template: '<div ng-controller="myCtrl">The rest of your directive can go here<div>'
  }
}
```